# Error: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: android-studio, duplicates

I'm trying to add a library to my project, right now my current `build.gradle` is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.guycohen.cheaters"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
            // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.whl.handytabbar:library:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
}
```

When I add a new library

```
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:PhoneTutorial:1.+@aar'
```

I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:      android/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2$1.class
```

I've tried to fix this issue by adding

```
configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }
```

I couldn't find a duplicate class in my project.

I'm sure whether if I could delete the duplicate entry it would run perfectly, but I'm not sure how I'd find it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.github.navasmdc:PhoneTutorial:1.+@aar') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, I'm still getting Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2$1.class ----------------> I don't understand why i'm getting on duplicate if I exclude the support library ? it's not even logical.

Comment: add it to facebook dependency too compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

Answer (score 1):

I use this to replace all support libraries versions with the latest one that i use in gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "26.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this versions in build.gradle file.**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your Error:**

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:      android/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2$1.class

**Step 1:**
In this case main hint is **android/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2$1.class**

**Step 2:** Searching for the class, in your case the  "PrintHelperKitkat.class" (in AndroidStudio just hit Ctrl+N on Windows or CMD-O on Mac)

**Step 3:** See which jar contains it - Android Studio will write it in the popup.

**Step 4:** Exclude it from all builds,

for example:

com.android.support:support-v4:_____

```
compile('your_conflicted_dependency')
    {
         exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

> In my case my one dependency also included in my another AAR. So I
>   deleted that dependency

Answer (score 0):

**I was faced the same issue. I solved it by,**

Make sure that in all imported project's `build.gradle` file should have same `compileSdkVersion` and `dependencies` versions like in your project's `build.gradle` file.
It will remove this error.