# Dealing with duplicate entries in AndroidStudio: java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, spongycastle

*EDIT: Solution from [Error: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769483/error-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry) doesn't work here, because I don't have problem with support-v4 module*

I'm trying to build an Android project which uses SpongyCastle, but unfortunately it requires `javax.naming` package from `jndi` library.
I added jndi and even javaEE to make it work, but gradle still has problem with running a project (build is successful)

My gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "grylls.cryptotexting"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    compile files('lib/jndi-1.2.1.jar')
}
```

Gradle throws this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.> 
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:java.util.zip.ZipException: 
duplicate entry:javax/mail/AuthenticationFailedException.class
```

When I tried to exclude `javax.mail` from `javax:javaee-api:7.0` I got:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Where can I find this duplication of javax.mail which by the way I don't even need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769483/error-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To properly include SpongyCastle I had to make a change in dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.51.0.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.51.0.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.51.0.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pg:1.51.0.0'
}
```

Create a class that inserts BouncyCastle Provider

```
import android.app.Application;
import java.security.Security;
public class Dynks extends Application {
    static { Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1); }
}
```

and include it in AndroidManifest.xml under "application" tag:

```
...
    <application
            android:name="Dynks"
...
```