# Android Studio java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: android

here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.arefin.lasttrykinvay"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name:'kinvey-android-2.10.5', ext:'aar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile google-http-client-1.19.0.jar 
    compile google-http-client-android-1.19.0.jar
    compile google-http-client-gson-1.19.0.jar 
    compile google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar 
    compile gson-2.1.jar guava-18.0.jar 
    compile jackson-core-2.1.3.jar 
    compile java-api-core-2.10.1.jar 
    compile java-api-core-2.10.5.jar 
    compile kinvey-android-2.10.5.aar
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And here is the error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/kinvey/java/AbstractClient$Builder$Option.class
```

When I remove the

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

That above error fixes but other functions dont work properly . Like values/style cant not find

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

How can I that duplicate entry error ?

Comment: Do u have any jars in ur lib folder?

Comment: Please update your build-tools version and set that to you gradle file. Hopefully it will work !

Comment: Yes I have kinvey-api jars in libs folder .

Comment: @Yasin Arefin can u list the jars in ur lib folder?

Comment: google-http-client-1.19.0.jar
google-http-client-android-1.19.0.jar
google-http-client-gson-1.19.0.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar
gson-2.1.jar
guava-18.0.jar
jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
java-api-core-2.10.1.jar
java-api-core-2.10.5.jar
kinvey-android-2.10.5.aar

Comment: @YasinArefin why u r using multiplr core jars? Remove duplicate jar and try again.

Comment: Which jars to remove ?

Comment: @YasinArefin u have to choose that. Try this keep only the last aar file and remove all jars and check one by one.

Comment: Cool that worked for me. I just kept the aar file. Now have to try if the app works properly or not :(

Comment: But did they give all those jars though we dont need it ?

Comment: @YasinArefin May be that aar file itself includes those so may not use all again. Can I post it as anwer will u accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Remove duplicate library dependencies.

Although the OP didn't write this out, if you look at the comments on the original question, you'll see that they have a number of `.jar` library files in the `libs` directory, which are all included in the following line:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  //...
}
```

In one of their comments, they list the following files in their `libs` directory:

- `google-http-client-1.19.0.jar`
- `google-http-client-android-1.19.0.jar`
- `google-http-client-gson-1.19.0.jar`
- `google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar`
- `gson-2.1.jar`
- `guava-18.0.jar`
- `jackson-core-2.1.3.jar`
- `java-api-core-2.10.1.jar` **Duplicate!**
- `java-api-core-2.10.5.jar` **Duplicate!**
- `kinvey-android-2.10.5.aar`

You can clearly see that `java-api-core` is included twice, once for the `2.10.1` version and once for the `2.10.5` version. The build system isn't smart enough to only bring one of these in, and it shouldn't have to be. The user should tell the build system which libraries to be included and which version of each to include.

**By removing the `java-api-core-2.10.1.jar` file from the `libs` directory, the error should be resolved.**

This might not be the exact problem you're running into but it's likely the result of something similar.

To help avoid these situations, here are a couple of best practices:

#### 1. Don't use `compile fileTree...`.

Instead of hiding away all the `.jar` files that you're including, explicitly state which files you're compiling under `dependencies {}`. This will make it easier to see when you have duplicates, conflicts and other issues like this.

#### 2. Use Maven instead of `.jar` files as much as possible.

Although it wouldn't catch this, by using Maven and putting the same dependency twice with different versions it should only resolve one of those dependencies (I think) and avoid a cryptic error like you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the duplicate jars and use only required jar and aar files.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these code to your Gradle.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    }

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

or add this class to your Application Class if you dont have Application class just crate it...

```
public class SomeApplication extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MultiDex.install(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }       
}
```

Comment: sometimes you have to do the both thing... :)

Comment: I did both you told me . Still the error is coming :(

Comment: if it is a zip file why don't you remove the jars which you don't want?

Comment: I need all those jars for the kinvey api to work properly .

Comment: try this answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769483/error-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry

Comment: it cant be it because some jars are using in support:appcompat-v7. that is why you getting this error. try manually removing one by one and sync the gradle. verse case :P