# How to fix duplicate entry ZipException in android?

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I am using EBS payment gateway in my android application. EBS includes volley library in its folder. Also I use volley library for my project.So I get an exception like this.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class
```

And below is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations{
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley', module: 'toolbox'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.nivedha.rents"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
   compile project(':EBS')
}
```

Help me out to fix this issue..

Comment: Go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769483/error-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry

Comment: I use "all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley', module: 'toolbox'" here. But I am not sure how to give the module in this line. @CandleCoder

Answer (score 5):

Do like this :

When you added `com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0` your some of the dependencies got clashed

So, now what you have to do is

1. Search <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in android studio for the class `AuthFailureError.class`
2. See which jar contains this and remove it like below (This is just as an example/You have to figure out the duplicate class and manually remove it)

```groovy
configurations{
    all*.exclude module: 'toolbox'
}
```