# Android error: Gradle Duplicate Entry: java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When i try to run the app am getting an error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/IntegerRes.class

I tried the gradlew app: dependencies and its result is

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2
+--- project :seekArc_library
+--- project :socialauthandroid
+--- project :SwipeMenuListView
+--- com.android.support:design:24.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.0.0
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.0.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.0.0 (*)
\--- com.android.support:support-v13:24.0.0
```

I think it is because of the maven dependecies. so I tries exulde option for support v4, but no use.

gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
  compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
  compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar')
  compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
  compile project(':seekArc_library')
  compile project(':socialauthandroid')
  compile project(':SwipeMenuListView')
  compile('com.android.support:support-v13:24.0.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
  compile ('com.android.support:design:24.0.0'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
```

}

I tried rebuild and clean thew project , also sync but no use. Issue is still remain

Can any one please help me.

Comment: comment `exclude module: 'support-v4'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya both? or just `design:24` one?

Comment: yes I tried both case, comment both , but the issue still exist, and then i comment for support design , still the issue exist @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: tried both , issue still exist @Jordi Castilla

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29127909/3850595), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29880863/3850595) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30806952/3850595)

Comment: i tried all,issue still remain .here the issue i duplicate entry for IntegerRes.class @Jordi Castilla

Comment: deelting gradle folder and recompiling doesn't solve problem either?

Comment: i delete the build.gradle from the app , then sycn and rebuild the project , but the gradle is not creating @Jordi Castilla

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117293/discussion-between-binil-surendran-and-jordi-castilla).