# Duplicate entry: META-INF/ when build .apk

Tags: android

I am getting following error. I am stuck on this error from last 2 days, I don't know how resolve this error. Anybody please help me out to resolve this error. Thanks in advance

```html
   Execution failed for task ':app:buildProductionBuildDebugPreBundle'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: **I have solved it by this solution in link** [Solution is available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58724209/6826102)

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude this files by adding those lines to your modules `build.gradle`:

```
android {

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
  }
}
```

add the `packagingOptions` attribute into the `android` section of the gradle file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately this solution is not working for me.

Comment: Neither for me. What is weird that it fails while transforming support-v4.aar – is this a part of androidx?